# Subscription metadata should be included in the BINARY

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

My app uses a auto-renewing subscription, and Apple rejected it:

> We noticed that your app or its metadata did not fully meet the terms
>   and conditions for auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in
>   Schedule 2, section 3.8(b) of the Paid Applications agreement.
>
> Your app's **binary** did not include the following information about the auto-renewable nature of the subscription:
>
> - Title of publication or service
> - Length of subscription (time period and content or services provided during each subscription period)
> - Price of subscription, and price per unit if appropriate
> - Payment will be charged to iTunes Account at confirmation of purchase
> - Subscription automatically renews unless auto-renew is turned off at least 24-hours before the end of the current period
> - Account will be charged for renewal within 24-hours prior to the end of the current period, and identify the cost of the renewal
>
> Subscriptions may be managed by the user and auto-renewal
>   may be turned off by going to the user's Account Settings after
>   purchase
>
> Any unused portion of a free trial period, if offered, will
>   be forfeited when the user purchases a subscription to that
>   publication, where applicable
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app or its metadata to
>   include the missing information. Adding the above information to the
>   StoreKit modal alert is not sufficient; the information must also be
>   displayed within the app itself, and it must be displayed clearly and
>   conspicuously during the purchase flow without requiring additional
>   action from the user, such as opening a link.
>
> If the above information is in your app, please reply to this message
>   in Resolution Center to provide details on where to locate it.

We have a Terms and Conditions button that opens a web view. We can put it inline in the app as a view controller that opens when you tap the button, rather than a web view.

Have you gotten this rejection, and what did you have to do to get them to approve it?

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: We made it a view controller that displays a string hardcoded in the app, rather than a web view.